# Custom model validator does not work on edit

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I wrote a validator for my model which is:

```
def validate_is_default(value):
    if Wizard.objects.filter(set_as_default=True).count() == 1:
        if value is True:
            raise ValidationError(_('You can mark only one configuration as default'))
        else:
            raise ValidationError(_('You have to mark one configuration as default'))
```

And I have model when I use it:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Wizard name'), default='Default', max_length=32, blank=False)
    ...
    set_as_default = models.BooleanField(_('Set as default setup'), default=False, validators=[validate_is_default])
```

In validator I wanted to check if there is only one record in database that has set_as_default=True. This works fine when I add new record, but fails when I try to edit one. How to solve this?

I use this in admin panel. I would not like to change default form, but solve it somehow using this validators. Is it possible?

Comment: "Does not work" is not a useful description. How does it fail?

Comment: Now I check set_as_default in model save. If one is set as default then I change this field to false, and set true for new record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your database backend, columns using `models.BooleanField` won't always be given the Python values `True` and `False` by Django (in particular, if you're using MySQL, you'll get back `1` or `0` because MySQL has no boolean type and Django simply uses a tinyint).

Therefore, instead of the clause `if value is True:`, write just `if value:`. Like so:

```
def validate_is_default(value):
    if Wizard.objects.filter(set_as_default=True).count() == 1:
        if value:
            raise ValidationError(_('You can mark only one configuration as default'))
        else:
            raise ValidationError(_('You have to mark one configuration as default'))
```

You haven't provided enough information for me to conclusively state that this is your problem, but it's likely that it is.